# How to get Euclidean Distance to include all input features?

Tags: arcmap, distance, proximity

I've run Euclidean distance on a water source dataset. Water is represented as polygons and I run the Euclidean Distance tool in ArcMap. It appears to work great but when I zoom in I notice that some of the smaller water source polygons have not been included as results show the area as far from a source. Is there anyway I can make the tool include every polygon, not matter it's size in the analysis?

Comment: Reduce cell size in environment settings.

Comment: @FelixIP This worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Changed output cell size to 30 from 1045, which allowed for smaller water sources to show.